# API Version 45 Error

Tags: api

When trying to log into the API Version `45` in Production environment I am receiving the following error.

> UNKNOWN ERROR: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'soapclient/sforce.450.partner.wsdl' : failed to load external entity "soapclient/sforce.450.partner.wsdl

Comment: in 2 words -- Version 45 is Spring '19, it is not available in production so far, will be available in approx 4 weeks

Comment: @kurunve you should roll up your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Version 45 corresponds to Spring '19, it was not available in production on the moment when this question was opened, but should be available now, since all the production organizations should have already migrated to Spring '19.